# R: Calculate factors of a number in R

Tags: r, factors

I was playing with R a little bit and I came out with this behavior that I don't understand:

```
num <- seq(1,20,1)

num[num %% c(1,2) == 0]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

So it seems to be an analog expression of

```
num[num %% 1 == 0 | num %% 2 == 0]
```

But when I do the following gets weird:

```
num[num %% c(1,3) == 0]
[1]  1  3  5  6  7  9 11 12 13 15 17 18 19

num[num %% c(1,4) == 0] 
[1]  1  3  4  5  7  8  9 11 12 13 15 16 17 19 20
```

I have been thinking about it, but I can't come out with an explanation for this. It's just out of curiosity, but if someone has a reason it would be very interesting to hear!.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look on the recycling rule! (in [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) in Section 2.2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jogo says, it's the recycling rule.

The result of `num %% 1` is

`[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

whilst the result of `num %% 3` is

`[1] 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2`

Looking at the result of `num %% c(1,3)`

`[1] 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 2`

The first number in the result is taken from the first number of the `num %% 1` result, the second from the second number of the `num %% 3` result, the third from the third in `num %% 1` and so on.